# Why don't parties run primary elections instead of the government?

Tags: united-states, election, voting, parties, primaries

Why does the government run primary elections instead of the parties?

Comment: If this question is about a particular country, please tag you question with said country.

Comment: Given the context this must be USA so as Joe C suggested I added that as a tag. E.g. Denmark primaries is just something an assembly does in the party itself

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, parties run primaries. They are required by law (and ultimately by the constitution) to follow democratic principles, but they are generally only open to dues-paying party members and the dates are set by the parties.

Often party conventions are called on several levels. Grassroots members elect delegates to a convention, which elects either candidates for local elections or delegates to the federal convention.